# How to reduce size of Distribution database used in MSSQL replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

Size of distribution database used in transactional replication has increased significantly, it is almost double of the database being replicated.
Size of replicated database is 18 GB and distribution database is 35 GB.

Is this normal? If so can someone point me to resources where I can get some information about how to assess size of distribution database in future.

Please note, it is SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the free space in the database?
Also check if the Clean Up Task for the Distribution database is working fine.

Comment: clean up task was not working earlier, I fixed it yesterday.
Free space is 28GB :). I think the culprit was the cleanup task.
Should I simply shrink the database?